# Matching route to preselected value in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In the first componen I have several buttons that should redirect to certain nested route based on which button was clicked.

```
<btn to="financials/financialdata"></btn>

<btn to="financials/revenuedata"></btn>
```

This route displays a component that should be different depending on the route name. The most important thing is the options form where the value that is preselected matches the route name but a bit differently.
Here is how i confiugred that route in router

```
{ path: '/financials/:name', component: dataview}
```

This is my select form:

```
      <v-select
          :items="datasets"
          label="Solo field"
          item-text="text"
          item-value="value"
          v-model="data"
          dense
          solo
        ></v-select>
```

And here is the options:

```
datasets: [
        {
          text: "Financial Condition",
          value: 'A'
        },
{
          text: "Revenue Data",
          value:'B'

        }]
```

So how can match the route name with the value in the `dataset`, so that i can be preselected in the select form?
I also want to display which route is currently displayed in the title on the component page:

`<h1>{{title}}</h1>`

So based on the route param it would display the same title as selected in the form (so based on the `dataset`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your router config... add a name to the route or use meta parameter

in routes file:

```
  {
    path: "/revenue",
    name: "Revenue",
    component: Revenue
  }
```

in select component:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      datasets: [
        {
          text: "Financial Condition",
          value: "A"
        },
        {
          text: "Revenue Data",
          value: "Revenue"
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.selectValue = this.$route.name;
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: The thing is I dont want to create so many routes and give each name. Is it possible without that? just `path: '/financial/:name'` and somehow give it name?

Comment: you use fullPath instead of using route name
```
this.selectValue = this.$route.fullPath
```

Answer (score 0):

In your component, in the created function you could set or update the datasets or what you are binding the form to with the route params.

```
created: function () {
            this.yourformdata = this.$route.params.thevalue 

        },
```

Comment: And how this would be transformed so that it can match the desired name?

Comment: You might consider writing the route and route params to the console so you can further see what is available to you. I'd also recommend the vue dev tools chrome extension to really explore the values that are available in the route.